# UITableView Cells Are Showing Only 1 Cell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I've been trying to build a basic Swift app to display cars. I have a UITableView setup. Currently I have two cars defined, but only 1 is displaying for some reason.

Model.swift

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

public enum CarColor {
case White
case Blue
case Black
case Red
}

class Model {

var title: String
var description: String
var image: UIImage
var color: CarColor

init(titled: String, description: String, imageName: String){
    self.title = titled
    self.description = description
    if let img = UIImage(named:imageName){
        image = img
    } else {
        image = UIImage(named:"default")!
    }
    color = .White
    }
}
```

ModelLine.swift

```
import Foundation

class ModelLine {

var name: String
var models: [Model]


init(named: String, includeModels: [Model]){
    name = named
    models = includeModels
}

class func modelLines() -> [ModelLine]{
    return[self.hondaCRV(), self.hondaPilot()]
}

private class func hondaCRV() -> ModelLine {
    var models = [Model]()
    models.append(Model(titled:"2016 Honda CR-V", description:"All day and into the night, CR-V delivers dynamic crossover performance and style. It's also incredibly spacious, with luxury amenities at the top of its class.", imageName: "crv"))
    return ModelLine(named:"Honda CR-V", includeModels: models)
}

private class func hondaPilot() -> ModelLine {
    var models = [Model]()
    models.append(Model(titled:"2016 Honda Pilot", description:"2016 Model", imageName: "pilot"))
    return ModelLine(named:"Honda Pilot", includeModels: models)
}
```

HondaModelTableViewController.swift

```
import UIKit

class HondaModelTableViewController: UITableViewController {

var models: [Model]{
    var modelLines = ModelLine.modelLines()
    return modelLines[0].models
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
}


override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of sections
    return 1
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return models.count
}


override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("modelCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as UITableViewCell

    let model = models[indexPath.row]  
    cell.textLabel?.text = model.title
    cell.detailTextLabel?.text = model.description
    cell.imageView?.image = model.image

    return cell
}
```

Comment: This is the issue: var modelLines = ModelLine.modelLines()
    return modelLines[0].models. However, your code looks a bit ovecomplicated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are just returning the first array of ModelLine, which only has one car in it.

```
class func modelLines() -> [ModelLine]{
          //index 0         index 1
    return[self.hondaCRV(), self.hondaPilot()]
}

var models: [Model]{
    var modelLines = ModelLine.modelLines()
    return modelLines[0].models //Only index 0 being called.
}
```

Since you have your model set up in a 2 dimentional array of sorts, seeing as `self.hondaPilot()` may be implemented later to have return more than  one `Model`, I suggest setting up your `ModelLines` in sections and your `Model` as the rows in that section.

```
    var modelLines : [ModelLines] { //Use modelLines instead so you have access to ALL cars of all modelLines.
        return ModelLine.modelLines()
     } 
    override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of sections4
        return modelLines.count //This will give you 2 sections.
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return modelLines[section].count //Gives you number of models in each modelLines section.
    }
```

Comment: I restructured my model so hondaCars would have both cars. But thanks! Gonna mark this as correct, since it brought to my attention the over-complication of my design.

Answer (score 1):

In

```
var models: [Model]{
    var modelLines = ModelLine.modelLines()
    return modelLines[0].models
}
```

You're returning just the first element from the array.

Answer (score 0):

In `HondaModelTableViewController` you're returning only the first object of the `modelLines` array.

Replace `return modelLines[0].models` with:

```
for model in modelLines {
    return model.models
}
```

Answer (score 0):

in numberOfRowsInSection, you return the number of models in modelLines[0]

You have loaded the Honda CR-V into modelLine[0], and the Honda Pilot into modelLines[1]

You're only getting one row returned, because that's how much data you have specified.  If you want both to appear in the same table, you need to sort out your constructors

Answer (score 0):

The parts need to be addressed:

```
    // Part I:
    //    var models: [Model]{
    //        var modelLines = ModelLine.modelLines()
    //        return modelLines[0].models
    //    }
    let models = ModelLine.modelLines()

    // Part II:
    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as UITableViewCell
        let model = models[indexPath.row].models[0]
        cell.textLabel?.text = model.title
        cell.detailTextLabel?.text = model.description

        return cell
    }
```